# Implement text matching like solr in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, solr, pattern-matching

I am working on a test based Q & A application. The questions on the application mainly have two or three words as the answer.

```
Example  : Q.  Who founded Google ? 

           A.  Larry Page , Sergei Brin
```

There are no options for the answer, the user has to actually type it in. Plus in some cases there might be a synonym for the answer.

Example: USB Drive, Universal Serial Bus Drive, Pen Drive are all correct answers for the question: What is meant by nerd bling?

I have worked with solr before and it's full text search is powerful enough to do a match, consider synonyms and give a score for the match. However, I need to match the answers in my RoR application. Instead of writing my own regex to handle the task, I am wondering if there are some libraries that I could look at within RoR for this.

Also, if I were to look under the hood of solr and take inspiration from the code there to create a library of my own, please suggest files/modules I should be looking at (since I barely have any idea about Java).

Comment: Why not to use one of many Solr adapters for ruby?

Comment: You do seem to have options in the question. What do you mean there are no options?

Answer (score 0):

Try using elasticsearch which allows RESTFUL search. Refer to www.elasticsearch.org/